# Windows 2012 Server, DNS resolve host for client

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, hosts, local, resolve

I've been looking for way to resolve host name for client on Windows Server 2012, just like if I added it to `hosts` file of the client workstations running Windows 7/8.

In `hosts` file I would add following entries as example:

```
192.168.12.145    linux.example.com
192.168.12.145    site.example.com
192.168.12.145    services.example.com
```

So client computers could connect to the address with the URL instead of IP, the machine on the other end of the address is server with Debian installed on it, running other services in which I would like to connect to with local connection.

Comment: What do you mean by "client"? DNS client? RDP-connected client? Domain client?

Comment: client computer, workstations that are connected to the active directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just install a DNS server or use an existing one in your environment?

Comment: I've DNS on the server 2012 but i've not yet figured out how to add "external device" or whatever that is not bound to windows server enviroment, if you know good guide/tutorial how to do this, I would aprreciate it.

Comment: Just add the records.. like any other record. You can follow the directions [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1954305/adding-dns-host-record-windows-server-2012-dns-server.html) if you need help.

Comment: I've done that and the record is still there but it doesn't seem to resolve it, flushed dns to see if that was the problem but no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

You can put the host entries into `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, for example `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.  This file serves the same purpose and has the same format as /etc/hosts in Linux, so it will allow network clients on that host to resolve those hostnames to their IP addresses.

Comment: This is what I would do if I added the entry to the clients, the file on server doesn't affect the clients.